# How can I increase the time of splash screen when not created any activity for splash?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have not created separate activity for splash screen but added a theme:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

and just updated the manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

my splash xml is:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I found all the answers which are just to increase time with the separate splash activity.

Comment: You need a separate activity which will transition after a certain time has passed. Otherwise... how do you expect to be able to do it?

Comment: Since your `MainActivity` is both the main activity and a splash screen, an alternative is to put code in your main activity which will keep it in "splash state" for a certain time, and then do what it's supposed to do...

Answer (score 1):

**It might not be the answer, but just wanted to clear something.(or for people who will visit this link in future).**

You know what.. most of the people think that `Splash Screen` is just for showing **Interactive UI** to the user.

But trust me it is more useful than your expectations.
It offers a unique way to Initialize the app's resources and checking properties etc.

You can do network check or lot of work in background that needed to be done before the user interact with app.

**That's the actual motive of splash screen**, not just showing the App logo or welcome message.

So, keep it simple.

Now, for you.. i will suggest.. use separate `Activity`. :)

Comment: I was going to write something related but then fear of downvotes stopped me.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar Oohhhhh...great  :D